# It is possible to assign a detail join to it's own cell in the resultset?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a fairly simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product
LEFT JOIN tbl_product_subject ON tbl_product_subject.product_id = tbl_product.id
WHERE tbl_product.type = 5
ORDER BY tbl_product.id DEC
```

And this kind of works, it will give me however many rows there are in `tbl_product_subject` indexed by the duplication of the `tbl_product` fields.

This is not what I want though.

What I want to have only one row per `tbl_product` fields and have the `tbl_product_subject` detail join iterated within that record but, to make things more difficult, not as a comma deliminated list wthin a single field.

Instead I want a field per result of detail join, for example:

```
tbl_product.id
123
tbl_product_subject.id1
1
tbl_product_subject.id2
2
tbl_product_subject.id3
3
tbl_product_subject.id4
4
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you use UNION within sub-queries in mysql?

Comment: @bf2020 apparently it seems possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159384/union-as-sub-query-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentionend in the comments, you can achieve the desired result by using union (all):

```
(
    SELECT 
        p.id AS id, 
        p.id AS pid 
    FROM 
        tbl_product p
) 
UNION ALL 
(
    SELECT 
        s.id AS id, 
        s.product_id AS pid 
    FROM 
        tbl_product_subject s
) 
ORDER BY pid, id;
```

---

If you want, you can also add some "labels" (I used them for "debugging"):

```
(
    SELECT  
        CONCAT("prod: ", p.id) AS id,  
        p.id AS pid  
    FROM 
        tbl_product p
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT
        CONCAT("sub: ", s.id) as id,  
        s.product_id AS pid  
    FROM 
        tbl_product_subject s
)
ORDER BY pid, id;
```

Comment: Unfortauntely it actually gives me: prod: 3  3
sub: 44  3
prod: 5  5
sub: 133  5
prod: 6  6
sub: 141  6
prod: 8  8 as separate rows, but I will work on it

Comment: Ok, so how do you want it? Everything in one cell?

Comment: Everything in one row

Comment: 1 row per product, but one col for each subject?

Comment: 1 row per poduct with each subject as a new cell within the row

Comment: Afaik, it's not possible to have a dynamic amount of columns in a mysql select statement.. therefore you'll may have to use a procedure or so to achieve this, I think.
Maybe I'll try to find a solution if I find some more time l8a.

Is it so important, to get the result set in that format? What do you want to do? Maybe there are solutions where you don't need a dynamic number of cells / columns.

Comment: Not anymore, tbh. The task has since passed. It was mainly to get a report out in this format and I was interested if it could be done in SQL alone